# What should I use to create a python based web application that needs to run on a local server?

Tags: web-apps, python, web-server, hosted

I need to create an web application using python and deploy it on a local server so that any system connected locally to that server can use that app.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly look at using something like [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) inside of a [docker](https://www.docker.com/) container e.g. the [standard python container](https://hub.docker.com/_/python/).

This combination should have minimum security risks and allow easy portability & scaling.

There is a nice walk through of using Docker Compose to run a  simple Django/PostgreSQL app [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/django/).

You may find it worth looking at [Gunicorn](https://gunicorn.org/) - have a look at [Dockerizing Django with Postgres, Gunicorn, and Nginx](https://testdriven.io/blog/dockerizing-django-with-postgres-gunicorn-and-nginx/).

There are a number of Python web frameworks available but Django is one of the more popular so lots of support and advice is available.